# Mapping NativeQuery results when using inner join

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the follow situation:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "TB_A")
public class A implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_B")
    private B b;

}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "TB_B")
public class B implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_B")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<C> c = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name = "TB_C")
public class C implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CD_B")
    private B b;

}
```

I need to run the follow code:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TB_A a "
            + "INNER JOIN TB_B b ON ... "
            + "LEFT JOIN TB_C c ON ... ";

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, A.class);

List<A> AList = query.getResultList();

for(A a : AList) {
    List<c> CList = a.getB().getC();
}
```

Analising the executed queries, I notice that JPS is running a SELECT each time I access elements B and C.

How can I correctly map this nativeQuery to use the lazyLoad?

- Obs: I MUST use NativeQuery, because in my WHERE clause I need to use an especific function from Oracle. So JPQL is not an option for me (If I could use it, my life would be much more easy!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

What this line will do:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, A.class);
```

Is execute your SQL, then throw away anything not related to A.class.

Then your for loop:

```
for(A a : AList) {
    List<c> CList = a.getB().getC();
}
```

Fetches everything again.
Here you use JPA again, which doesn't know anything about the query you executed before.

In some cases, you can try to map to `C.class` instead.
Then you'll be able to avoid the loop entirely.
If in your case you need both A.class and C.class, you can look into ResultSetMapping instead: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/SqlResultSetMappingForHierarchicalEntity.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look into ResultSetMapping.